# Gradual increase in HTML slider as opposed to an equal increase

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic HTML slider which I have added JavaScript to to perform some calculations. The min number in my slider is 1 and the max is 25,001. This is a huge range, and because of this, it makes it difficult to select a specific number. (No input area or arrows because of the design I've been given)

What I need is to be able to select the lower numbers via a slider very similar to the slider on this page. https://thirst.io/pricing/

```
<div class="slider">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="25001">
</div>
```

Comment: Make it super wide?

Comment: With the design element I have been given, the card needs to be about 33% of the page.

Comment: Your "similar slider" allows direct entry of the value required. is that something that you would want too? or just the logarithmic slider? like 1, 2, 5, 10, 24, 120.... that slider has a difficult time with fine selection at the higher range too

Comment: They are using the [rc-slider](https://github.com/schrodinger/rc-slider), you may want to find something similar

Comment: It's fairly easy to duplicate the one in the link [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6pnf4ut/show)

Comment: Thank you Yogi, that's just what I needed.